# Function execute issue

Tags: php, function

the following code can't be worked. Though  the function was calling

```
$name1 = "apple";
$gender1 = "orange";
$country1 = "pepe";

function profile1($name1, $gender1, $country1)
{

    echo $name1 . "\n";
    echo $gender1 . "\n";
    echo $country1 . "\n";
}
profile1();
```

Comment: use as `profile1($name1, $gender1, $country1)`

Answer (score 0):

The function parameters `$name1`, `$gender1`, and `$country1` are separate and distinct from the variables declared outside the function. When you call the function without providing any arguments, the values of the parameters will be undefined.

You can either:

```
profile1( $name1, $gender1, $country1 );
```

or (not recommended!):

```
function profile1()
{
global $name1, $gender1, $country1;
echo $name1 . "\n";
echo $gender1 . "\n";
echo $country1 . "\n";
}

profile1();
```

Comment: The question is very common. please mark as duplicate if possible.

Comment: I would definitely not recommend using `global`!!